# How to count the number people on each day and group them using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this,

```
select distinct c.EMAIL, 
c.ORDER_CREATED_DATE as order_date, 
c.action_date , 
DATEDIFF(day,c.action_date,c.ORDER_CREATED_DATE) as diff

From Customers  c
```

Which returns the following results for example

```
EMAIL          ORDER_DATE      ACTION_DATE  DIFF
a@gmail.com    2021-04-26      2021-02-25   60
b@gmail.com    2021-03-15      2021-02-25   18
c@gmail.com    2021-03-05      2021-03-03   2
aa@gmail.com   2021-04-26      2021-02-25   60
```

What I want are 2 separate queries,

1. Count the number of people who bought on each day,

Expected results

```
day      email_count
0          0
2          1
18         1
60         2
```

2. count the number of people between days

   ```
   day  email_count
    0-7    1
    7-14   0
    14-28  1
   ```

I am not really getting how to get results something like this? Please can anyone help.

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL, but the query is not a valid MySQL query.  In addition, you seem to have asked two questions, which is one too many.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Sql-Server (not MySql).

You can generate intervals using a recursive query.

First query generate "intervals": generate 15 intervals of eight days each one, you can  change the condition to increment the quantity of intervals. Keep in mind that each interval end with some day and the next interval start with the same day, so a row could match two intervals.

```
WITH intervals AS (SELECT 0 AS f, 7 AS t

                   UNION ALL
                   
                   SELECT f + 7, t + 7
                   FROM intervals
                   WHERE t < 100),

     sqDiff AS (SELECT DISTINCT 
                          c.EMAIL, 
                          c.ORDER_CREATED_DATE as order_date, 
                          c.action_date,
                          DATEDIFF(day,c.action_date,c.ORDER_CREATED_DATE) AS diff
                FROM Customers c),
                
     sqCount AS (SELECT
                       diff,
                       count(EMAIL) AS cEmail
                 FROM sqDiff
                 GROUP BY diff)

SELECT CONCAT(i.f, '-', i.t) AS day , 
       CASE WHEN sq.cEmail IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE sq.cEmail END AS email_count
FROM intervals i
LEFT JOIN sqCount sq ON sq.diff between i.f AND i.t;
```

Output:

| day | email_count |
| --- | --- |
| 0-7 | 1 |
| 7-14 | 0 |
| 14-21 | 1 |
| 21-28 | 0 |
| 28-35 | 0 |
| 35-42 | 0 |
| 42-49 | 0 |
| 49-56 | 0 |
| 56-63 | 2 |
| 63-70 | 0 |
| 70-77 | 0 |
| 77-84 | 0 |
| 84-91 | 0 |
| 91-98 | 0 |
| 98-105 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

For first query you can try -

```
SELECT 0 DAYS, 0 EMAIL_COUNT
UNION ALL
SELECT diff, COUNT(diff)
  FROM (select distinct c.EMAIL, 
               c.ORDER_CREATED_DATE as order_date, 
               c.action_date , 
               DATEDIFF(day,c.action_date,c.ORDER_CREATED_DATE) as diff
          From Customers) c
 GROUP BY diff;
```

And for 2nd, the easiest possible method is -

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT diff, COUNT(diff)
               FROM (select distinct c.EMAIL,
                            c.ORDER_CREATED_DATE as order_date, 
                            c.action_date, 
                            DATEDIFF(day,c.action_date,c.ORDER_CREATED_DATE) as diff
                       From Customers) c
              GROUP BY diff)
SELECT '0-7' day, COUNT(CASE WHEN diff BETWEEN 0 AND 7 THEN email END) email_count
  FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT '7-14', COUNT(CASE WHEN diff BETWEEN 7 AND 14 THEN email END)
  FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT '14-28', COUNT(CASE WHEN diff BETWEEN 14 AND 28 THEN email END)
  FROM cte
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. the query looks a bit compliacted to me. Can this query be correct - select  count( c.EMAIL) as email_count, DATEDIFF(day,c.action_date,c.ORDER_CREATED_DATE) as day  from Customers.

Comment: You can run that and check by yourself.